# When setting <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext> in asp.net core 2.2 project custom middlewares not invoking

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

When I am setting the property PreserveCompilationContext to true like true in as.net core 2.2 mvc project custom middlewares are not invoking.

Comment: In the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40426665/what-is-the-use-of-preservecompilationcontext-under-build-option-in-project-json/40426998),svick says`As far as I know, this is primarily used for Razor pages. They are compiled at runtime, and the compiler needs access to reference assemblies, to make sure it compiles correctly. `I think the uninvoked of your middlewares maybe is caused by other reasons,such as the order you use in Configure.Or the middleware itself.Can you share more about your middleware?

Comment: This is s simple middleware having an Invoke method. See the middleware below

 `public class LSMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public LSMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {

            context.Response.Headers.Add("from-middleware", "MWData");
           _next(context);
        }

    }`